# Can't build iOS app with Flash Builder 4.6 and Air4.0

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

My Flash Builder 4.6 pure-Actionscript app gets automatically rejected by Apple if I submit without the new iOS7 icons. I have merged the new beta Air 4.0 SDK [(AIR 4 SDK & Compiler for Windows found here)](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html) with this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0
```

After that I can target the latest Air by putting inside the .xml description with no errors:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">
```

I also target the latest compiler (phrased correctly?) with this compiler directive:

```
-swf-version=23
```

The problem is that if I try to declare the new-sized icons inside the .xml:

```
<icon>
    <image57x57>icon/57X57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>icon/72X72.png</image72x72>
    <image76X76>icon/76X76.png</image76X76>
    <image114x114>icon/114X114.png</image114x114>
    <image120X120>icon/120X120.png</image120X120>
    <image144x144>icon/144X144.png</image144x144>
    <image152X152>icon/152X152.png</image152X152>
</icon>
```

I get the following "unexpected element" errors when trying to "Export Release Build" for iOS:

[image: error window image]

Am I missing something obvious? If there is no official workaround, does anyone know of a way to include the new icons with hacks/third-party tools/Mac tools etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what I've seen, the only elements causing trouble are those whose declarations use upper case X's. Downcase the X's and it should work.

```
<icon>
    <image57x57>icon/57X57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>icon/72X72.png</image72x72>
    <image76x76>icon/76X76.png</image76x76>
    <image114x114>icon/114X114.png</image114x114>
    <image120x120>icon/120X120.png</image120x120>
    <image144x144>icon/144X144.png</image144x144>
    <image152x152>icon/152X152.png</image152x152>
</icon>
```